# saving aspx page to html

Tags: asp.net, html, save

while saving my aspx page as webpage(.htm)

i did not get the values assigned to labels/textbox. i got oly the label. 
eg: customer name: xxxx

in the saved file(.html) i got oly customer name:

and not the values when i store as .html. why???

Answer (score 0):

May be those values are assigned using JavaScript on page load or any other event. Try opening that file in a browser.